# libcurl on Windows question

Tags: c++, windows, libcurl

Just downloaded libcurl and built it on Windows, using VC2008. It came with a project, I build it, a static library (release). 
I use it in my console win32 app, it does not link, unresolved symbols. So I do a dumpbin /exports on the libcurl.lib and nothing. Puzzling...

As part of the libcurl distro, there is a curl project that uses the libcurl.lib. It does not have any problems linking to the same lib.

Any ideas, what i am doing incorrectly?

Thanks
Reza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, the answer was "in front of my eyes". I needed to use the compiler directive specific to the static lib which is /D "CURL_STATICLIB".